# Create array with sum of values in first array where clause

Tags: php, arrays, sum

The first array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 100
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => 7
            [amount] => 16.00
            [employee_name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 100
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => 6
            [amount] => 2.00
            [employee_name] => John
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 573
            [year] => 2014
            [month] => 7
            [amount] => 10.00
            [employee_name] => Bill
        )
)
```

I want to create an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 100
            [year] => 2014
            [amount_month7] => 16.00
            [amount_month6] => 2.00
            [employee_name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 573
            [year] => 2014
            [amount_month7] => 10.00
            [amount_month6] => 0.00
            [employee_name] => Bill
        )
)
```

So the amounts for each month are summed for each employee.

Now I did succeed in getting this with a lot of ifs and elseifs but I wonder it might be better to do this with a foreach statement, but I can't find a way to sum values depending on other values. 
The statement should be something like

```
foreach 
if (employee_id, year and month) is the same, amount_month[month] += amount
```

Is there an easy way to do this with foreach?

Comment: Show your original SQL query. This is easier to do by changing your SQL than retrieving all records and then aggregating in PHP

Comment: Yes another option could be in changing the query or rather adding a new query because I need the current query for other functions. Would you suggest adding another query above fiddling with the existing array in PHP?

Comment: It's something that a database query can probably do a lot more efficiently, depending on the volumes of data that you're working with

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array_unique(array_map(
    function ($v) { return $v['employee_id']; },
    $array
));

$result = array();
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $result[] = array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($val) {
        return $v['employee_id'] == $val;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this reorganisation via PHP, rather than through SQL, it might be easier to create an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 100
            [year] => 2014
            [amounts] => Array
              (
                [6] => 2.00
                [7] => 16.00
              )
            [employee_name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_id] => 573
            [year] => 2014
            [amounts] => Array
              (
                [7] => 10.00
              )
            [employee_name] => Bill
        )
)
```

Comment: I would have to figure out how to get this array, though I think the conclusion is that there is not an easy solution with a foreach function or similar. The anwer below from hindmost doesn't give me the desired array. Actually the question boils down to how to make a pivot table from a table in the db.